# Parsing XML in JSP with JSTL

Tags: xml, xpath, jstl

I've got to parse xml code in a jsp (using JSTL). I want to retrieve only the `<title>` element content of the xml.

I retrieve the xml code (from eXist-db) using an XPath query, then I pass it as a string (in a `List<String>`) to my controller and finally I add it to the jsp requestScope.

When I use the JSTL in my jsp, however, I can't parse the xml I've got in my requestScope.

The **XML** code:

```
<poll xmlns="com.dot.bla.com/poll" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://com.dot.bla.com/poll poll.xsd">
    <pollHead>
        <code>1</code>
        <title>This is the title</title>
    </pollHead>
    <pollBody>
    </pollBody>
</poll>
```

Here's the **Controller** (within Spring framework):

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public String getAllPolls(Model model) throws RepositoryError {
    List<String> polls = service.getAllPollsSkeletons();
    model.addAttribute("polls",polls);
    return "common.index";
}
```

The **jsp**:

```
<c:forEach items="${polls}" var="poll">
  <x:parse doc="${poll}" var="output"/>
  <b>Title:</b>
  <x:out select="$output/pollHead/title"/><br/>
</c:forEach>
```

This doesn't work, it doesn't give me anything in my html source output. But if I just write

```
<x:out select="$output"/>
```

it will give me all the xml code contents, without any xml tag formatting.
What am I doing wrong? What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
<c:forEach items="${polls}" var="poll">
  <x:parse doc="${poll}" var="output"/>
  <b>Title:</b>
  <x:out select="$output/poll/pollHead/title"/><br/>
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have this xml with only one child inside one node you can skip the node title rather use xPath only

```
<c:forEach items="${polls}" var="poll">
<x:parse doc="${poll}" var="output"/>
  <b>Title:</b>
  <x:out select="$output///title"/><br/>
</c:forEach>
```